# Neo4j cypher query perfomance

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

I have the following cypher queries and their execution plans respectively,

**Before optimization**,

```
match (o:Order {statusId:74}) <- [:HAS_ORDERS] - (m:Member)
with m,o 
match (m:Member) - [:HAS_WALLET] -> (w:Wallet) where w.currentBalance < 250 
return m as Members,collect(o) as Orders,w as Wallets order by m.createdAt desc limit 10
```

[image]

---

**After optimization (db hits reduced by 40-50%)**,

```
match (m:Member) - [:HAS_ORDERS]->(o:Order {statusId:74})
with m, collect(o) as Orders
match (m) - [:HAS_WALLET] - (w:Wallet) where w.currentBalance < 250
return m as Members, Orders, w as Wallets 
order by m.createdAt desc limit 10
```

[image]

There are 3 types of nodes, Member, Order and Wallet. And the relation between them goes like this,

- *Member - [:HAS_ORDERS] -> Order*,
- *Member - [:HAS_WALLET] -> Wallet*

I have around 100k Member nodes (100k wallet) and almost 570k orders for those members.
I want to fetch all the members who have order status 74 and wallet balance less than 250, and the above query gives the desired result but it takes an average 1.5 sec to respond.

I suspect there is a still scope of optimization here but I'm not be able to figure out. I've added indexing on fields upon which I'm filtering the data.

I've just started exploring neo4j and not sure how can I optimize this.

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like "lac" or "lakh" here. We're not all from India.

Comment: Have you tried using EXPLAIN/PROFILE? This documentation helps: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/#execution-plans

Comment: @fbiville, Yeah I tried EXPLAIN & PROFILE and checked which part is slow, also I updated the query in the question which reduced the db hits by almost 40-50% and improved the time performance also. Still I'm looking how can I improve more.

Comment: Can you share the execution in the initial post? That may help figuring out the remaining bottlenecks.

Comment: 1 suggestion: you should be able to remove the WITH, merge the two MATCH patterns, and COLLECT only in the RETURN clause. That might help.

Comment: I've updated the question itself, described before after queries with their execution plans. 
Sure!
I'll try merge and check the performance again. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can leverage [index-backed ordering](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/advanced-example/#advanced-query-tuning-example-index-backed-order-by) to try a different approach here. By providing a type hint (something to indicate the property value is a string) along with the ordering by the indexed property, we can have the planner use the index to check :Member nodes in the order you want (by `m.createdAt DESC`) for free (meaning we don't need to check every :Member node and order them), and check each of those in the given order to find the ones that meet the desired criteria until we get the 10 you need.

From some back-and-forth on the Neo4j users slack, you mentioned that of your 100k :Member nodes, about 52k of them fit the criteria you're looking for, so this is a good indicator that we may not have to look very far down the ordered :Member nodes before finding the 10 that meet the criteria.

Here's the query:

```
MATCH (m:Member)
WHERE m.createdAt > ''  // type hint
WITH m
ORDER BY m.createdAt DESC
MATCH (m)-[:HAS_WALLET]->(w) 
WHERE w.currentBalance < 250 AND EXISTS {
    MATCH (m)-[:HAS_ORDERS]->(:Order {statusId:74})  
} 
WITH m, w
LIMIT 10
RETURN m as member, w as wallet, [(m)-[:HAS_ORDERS]->(o:Order {statusId:74}) | o] as orders
```

Note that by using an existential subquery, we just have to find one order that satisfies the condition. We wait until after the limit of 10 members is reached before using a pattern comprehension to grab all the orders for the 10 members.

Comment: Hii InverseFalcon, this approach is very much performant. It returns the result in 2ms. Thanks you so much for the help and the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried subqueries?  If you can use a subquery to shrink down the number of nodes before passing it along to subsequent queries.  (It would seem that an omniscient Query Planner could do this, but Cypher isn't there yet.). You may have to experiment with which subquery would filter out the most Nodes.

An example of using a subquery is here:
https://community.neo4j.com/t/slow-query-with-very-limited-data-and-boolean-false/31555

Another one is here:
https://community.neo4j.com/t/why-is-this-geospatial-search-so-slow/31952/24

(Of course, I assume you already have the appropriate properties indexed.)

Comment: Hii Clem, I would certainly like to thank you for your suggestion and the links you provided as a reference. It did help me with improving the query performance.
Db hits have been reduced also but still the query takes around ~400ms to respond. Still I'm trying to figuring out what and where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try posting your question in  https://community.neo4j.com/  You may get other solutions there.  How does the PROFILE look now?

Comment: Hii Clem, I posted there too and got the solution for it. Now it takes 2ms. You can see the answer given above. It works fine. Thanks!